# Group Policy Client failed the sign-in. Access is denied. Personal PC

Tags: security, user-accounts, login, group-policy

I got this message upon reboot “The Group Policy Client failed the sign-in. Access is denied.” on my personal PC. It is not managed by a domain, it has never touched any network other than my own. It is an offline Microsoft account (read local) and an administrator of the PC. It is the only account. Is my PC in trouble/compromised?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPVJ5.jpg

Comment: Can you start in Safe Mode?  Restart and very immediately press F8 repeatedly to start in Safe Mode

Comment: Well I was looking for assurance that I haven’t been compromised by anyone or any malicious software before I attempt to power it back on.

Comment: Your  system may be compromised by malware but I thought it to be worthwhile to start in safe mode to see if that works.

Comment: F8 did not put it into Safe Mode. Windows 10 Pro, custom built PC, Gigabyte z270XP-SLI motherboard with BIOS Version F7.

Comment: @Evan - If Windows fails to boot you will automatically be allowed to go into Advanced Startup. From Advanced Startup you can try Safe Mode

Comment: I forced safe mode by holding shift then clicking restart, then advanced settings, then startup settings, option six for safe mode with cmd prompt. The resolution looks to be 720p now. Should I login?

Comment: I would, at this point, make sure you have a good backup of data and email on the disk drive in the event you run out of options

Comment: Yes, try logging in at the Safe mode prompt

Comment: Well it’s been saying Welcome with a spinning loading sign consisting of five white balls for the past couple of minutes after typing in my password. My ethernet cable was pulled out before booting as well.

Comment: I have seen the above message from time to time and I think you are going to have to re-install Windows now.

Comment: If you're concerned about data on the system, *boot from a USB drive* and copy data. or better, make an image of the whole disk. This way, any change you make to the HDD can be undone. See https://www.pcworld.com/article/2147063/linux-to-the-rescue-how-ubuntu-can-help-a-computer-in-distress.html for example.